# Python lmdb version mismatch

Tags: windows, lmdb, python

I tried to explore the lmdb using  `python -mlmdb stat --env C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb`, but got the follwing error message:

> MDB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch

I am using the latest version of lmdb (0.98), Windows 10. What went wrong here? I will delete and re-sync the lmdb folder as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the lmdb folder and re-sync you will be in the same position. Just use the version (0.9.70) of mdb_stat that's in the Monero source tree (monero/external/db_drivers/liblmdb).

Also note, the *python* module version number (0.98) is *not* the lmdb version number. The *python* module you reference actually uses lmdb version 0.9.24. Therefore, if you need to use the python wrapper, you're going to have to build that first with the correct version of lmdb as used in Monero (0.9.70).

To use the LMDB library included in the Monero source code, uninstall your currently installed python lmdb module and reinstall following steps like:

```
cd ~/monero.git/external/db_drivers/liblmdb
make
cd ~
export LMDB_FORCE_SYSTEM=1
export LMDB_INCLUDEDIR=~/monero.git/external/db_drivers/liblmdb
export LMDB_LIBDIR=~/monero.git/external/db_drivers/liblmdb
pip install lmdb
```

Which ensures the version of LMDB the python module uses is the same version as used by Monero.

Comment: I've downloaded version 0.9.70 from https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb. How do I go about building the python wrapper with this version of lmdb? I'm sorry, I tried searching for guides on how to do it but couldn't find any.

Comment: Edit: also, the latest stable version of lmdb is 0.9.25, but you mentioned that Monero is using 0.9.70. How is that possible? Are the versions named seperately??

Comment: "How do I go about building the python wrapper with this version of lmdb?" <- see the docs: https://github.com/jnwatson/py-lmdb/blob/master/docs/index.rst#installation-unix

Comment: "also, the latest stable version of lmdb is 0.9.25, but you mentioned that Monero is using 0.9.70. How is that possible?" <- Because Monero doesn't use a *system* installed version of liblmdb, it uses a source version which gets built with Monero, and that is the latest version, 0.9.70.

Comment: I see, in that case, if I clone Monero, I should have 0.9.70 right? Right now I only have the GUI wallet, which is the source of my data.mdb.

Comment: "if I clone Monero, I should have 0.9.70 right?" <- Not quite no. Monero statically links the library it includes in its source tree, which is v0.9.70. So if you want to use the python module, you need to have that *module* built with the same version (0.9.70). Whether you use the code in the Monero source or grab liblmdb elsewhere, you have to build the python module with the correct version.

Comment: Ah I see, so if I replaced the liblmdb in the python wrapper with the one used in Monero and compiled it, I would be able to use the python wrapper to explore the Monero blockchain?

Comment: To anyone facing the same problem, I found the following library: https://pypi.org/project/lmdb-monero/ . However, it does not install properly through pip.